# Why is moment generating function represented using exponential rather than binomial series?

Tags: probability, random-variables, moment-generating-functions

A Moment Generating Function (MGF) of a random variable $X$ is [represented by an exponential](http://www.stat.ucla.edu/~nchristo/statistics100B/stat100b_mgf.pdf)

$$M_X(t) = E[e^{tX}]$$

Why isn't an MGF represented by [binomial expansion](https://math.oregonstate.edu/home/programs/undergrad/CalculusQuestStudyGuides/SandS/PowerSeries/mclaurin_list.html)?

For instance, $$M_X(t) = E\left[\frac{tX}{1-t}\right] = 1 + (tx)^2 + (tx)^3+ ... ... ... ...(1)$$

Hence, the derivatives are going to give the expected results.

So, what is wrong with binomial expansion?

Comment: Are you questioning a definition?

Comment: @StubbornAtom, No. I am asking for an explanation.

Comment: There is no random variable $X$ involved in your $M_X(t)$; it is a constant. And what 'expected results' are you talking about?

Comment: @StubbornAtom, it's a typographical mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$M_X(t)=E[e^{tX}]$ has the property $\left. \frac{d^n}{dt^n} M_X(t) \right |_{t=0}=E[X^n]$ (when it makes sense). $N_X(t)=E \left [ \frac{1}{1-tX} \right ]$ has the property that  $\frac{1}{n!} \left. \frac{d^n}{dt^n} N_X(t) \right |_{t=0}=E[X^n]$ (when it makes sense).

Either one would work for computing moments of bounded random variables. $N_X$ is not finite in a neighborhood of $t=0$ whenever $X$ is an unbounded random variable, whereas $M_X$ is finite in a neighborhood of $t=0$ whenever the tails of $X$  decay exponentially fast. $M_X$ also shows up explicitly in certain situations, for example in Cramer's theorem. $M_X$ also has at least one other very nice algebraic property that $N_X$ lacks: $M_{X+Y}=M_X M_Y$ when $X,Y$ are independent.